# Codeigniter 3 Download video

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I wrote a function in my controller for the user to download a video, but when they click on the download button it just loads the video path in the browser and does not download.

Here is my Controller code:

```
function download_video() 
{
  $this->load->helper('download');
  $video_path = $this->input->post('video_path');
  force_download($video_path, NULL);
}
```

Here is the JavaScript call to the Controller function:

```
// download btn
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#download').click(function(){
    window.location.href = "<?php echo 'http://www.example.com'.$video_path?>";
  });
});
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not providing video data in your second parameter:

```
force_download($video_path, NULL); // NULL should be the video data
```

Source: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html#force_download

Comment: I'm confused because the example says if you want to download an existing file do this: `force_download($video_path, NULL); `. I tried changing it around and everything looks good when using firebug but nothing downloads.

Comment: what do you get when you run the method straight from your URL? (i.e `localhost/myapp/download_video`)

Comment: nothing comes up. blank page. I am now able to get the video to download, but it does not play it's only 64 bytes.

Comment: I fixed my issue by wrapping my button in a form and submitting hidden fields to the download function and this worked.